# how to display the combined data of two tables using hasone relationship in controller

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have two tables :

```
employees(
  employe_id(primary key),
  emp_name,
  pay_id
)

pays(
  pay_id,
  hourlyrate
)
```

I have this code in **employemodel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\payModel;
class employeeModel extends Model
{

    protected  $table='employees';
    protected  $primaryKey='employe_id';
    public $timestamps=false;

    public function pay()
    {
    return $this->hasOne('App\payModel','pay_id');  
    }
}
?>
```

In **payModel** I have this code.

and in **employcontroller** in have this code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\employeeModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class employeController extends Controller
{
  public function display()
  {
    $display = employeeModel::find(1)->pay;
    return $display;
  }
}
```

When I use this I get only pays table details. I want combined result of two tables what I include in query.

When I use only `$display = employeeModel::find(1);` I am getting employee table details.

When in use `$display = employeeModel::find(1)->pay;` I am getting only pays table details?

```
class employeController extends Controller
{
  public function display()
  {
    //DB::enableQueryLog();
    $display = employeeModel::find(1)->pay;
    return $display;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your pay table, don't you have any id for employee?? As I see, you have pay_id is a primary key so how do you identify which pay record is there for a specific employee? Again, if you define an employee id here in pay table then inserting a record into it will have either an employee id or will be blank and also if two employees have same pay then you will have duplicate entries with different primary keys for both of the employees. So I would suggest to use many-to-many relationship first in database and then define Laravel models relationships according to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with, It will combined the two table,

```
class employeController extends Controller
{
  public function display()
  {
    //DB::enableQueryLog();
    $display = employeeModel::with('pay')->find(1);
    // dd($display);
    return $display;
  }
}
```

Comment: i am getting error message Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string@Md.Sukel Ali